# Changing Vcenter and Esxi IP's

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

Guys I have a Vcenter with lots of Esxi hosts and all of them have public IP addresses in their vmkernel's (managment) and now we need to change all of them to private IP is there any easy way to do it? I have an idea but I can't test it right now my idea is:

create another Vmkernel with a private IP address and enable management on it on the same standard switch (each server have a specific port and standard switch just for management ) and then change the Vcenter IP

I'm trying to find a way to avoid remove hosts and re-add them to Vcenter by the way all of my hosts have Dswitch with Lacp configuration also I'm not using the hostname my ESXi hosts added with their IP's.

Comment: What is the problem you solve by doing this?  Properly firewalled, it doesn't matter that an IP address is globally routable, even if you use it for private purposes.

Comment: all my Esxi host and vCenter have public IP and I don't like it, and I want to change their IP address and bring them behind a Firewall, my ESXi hosts have their firewall on but I don't like it because if I want to change anything in my network I must change them one by one, I want to change their firewall with some basic rules and range IP and control all permission to access to vCenter or ESXi hosts with a firewall.